# iOS proportional scaling of elements with relative distance to viewport

Tags: ios, layout

I'm a designer who requires the help of clever developers. Please don't throw me out just yet. =P

I currently have three artboards open in Sketch - iPhone SE, iPhone 8, iPhone XS Max device sizes. There's a circle shape, centered. All artboards are @1x. The shape with the size of 256 px will be the same size across all device sizes, as long as all devices are @1x. Merely the distance between the shape and the viewport increases.

No Scaling...

[image: Example with no scaling]

Is there a native iOS way to scale it based on the relative distance to the viewport?

Example with proportional scaling based on relative distance to viewport

[image: Example with proportional scaling based on relative distance to viewport]

Note that the shape will be made out of different elements, such as graphs that display a variety of information. I chose a simple shape to get the point across.

I ask this question because the circle shape will be a very prominent element, and it would be a shame if its size is severely limited by the fact that the iPhone SE needs to be properly supported.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: And what is your question??

Comment: Your question is how to do the 2nd images? Just add an `Aspect Ratio` & `Equal Width` to the main view then change it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following constraints:

1. Center the circle view horizontally relative to its superview.
2. Use an *Equal Widths* constraint to set the circle’s width equal to its superview’s width with a multiplier of `0.8`.
3. Set the height of the circle view equal to the width of the circle view using an *Aspect Ratio* constraint with multiplier `1`.
4. Finally add a top edge constraint from the circle to its superview with constant `32`.

That will make the circle 80% of the width of the view with the other 20% split evenly (10% each) to the two sides and the height will grow to match the width.

Comment: Thank you so much!

In case the circle is an element with a bunch of bar graphs with numbers and titles around it, will the entire element including the text and numbers be proportionally scaled?

Is it also possible to set precise pixel dimensions for the element per device? Meaning the device size gets checked and the element is rendered with the respective dimensions?

Comment: It sounds like your element is a custom view.  Every view is given its `rect` in its `draw(rect:)` routine.  The view should draw into that `rect` scaling things appropriately to fit.  You don't want to design around checking the device.  That is the wrong approach.  In iPad for instance, an app could be opened in Split View with another app and this is an entirely difference size and aspect ratio altogether. You should design relatively and proportionally.

Comment: It is indeed very much a custom view. Three in fact, each very different visualizations of data. Are there any losses of visual quality that stem from proportionally scaling as opposed to keeping it the same size (such as blurry lines/text)? I will definitely heed your advise in regards to checking device size, thank you very much! =)

Comment: The layout system only decides how big the views are.  It is the view's custom drawing code that must adjust to the new size.  The layout happens before the views are drawn and the view's need to take their size into account when drawing their content.  Auto Layout isn't in the business of taking fully drawn views and scaling their images.  It just figures out how big the views need to be, and then those views decide in their `draw(rect:)` functions how to draw the content into the `rect` specified by the layout system.